# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue that I can not figure out. I am trying to fadeOut a div and then remove it, and everything is working fine except I keep getting the error message above. Here is the function:

```
$(field).siblings('.error').fadeOut(200, function(){
   $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Pretty straight forward you would think. When I console.log `field`, I get the correct element and when I console.log `$(this)` inside that function, I also get the right element. The div fades out correctly, but for some reason, `$(this).remove()` is just killing it. Here are both elements:

`field`:

```
[input.user-name largeinput group-one, context: input.user-name largeinput group-one, jquery: "1.10.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
```

`$(this)`:

```
[div.error, context: div.error, jquery: "1.10.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
```

I looked into the object itself just to make sure that it is the correct div and it is. So why would this error be thrown on it? I had it working when I was calling it directly from a blur, but when I moved it into a function and called it via `validateField(field)`, it screws it up.

Obviously thats the issue, but I don't know why or how to fix it. Any advice from the community out there?

Comment: @BenM It seems he gets the correct thing: "when I console.log $(this) inside that function, I also get the right element."

Comment: Thats returns [div.error, context: div.error, jquery: "1.10.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…], which is exactly what I need.

Comment: Not a solution, but `field` seems to already be a jQuery object, so there is no need to to `$(field)`, you can just do `field.siblings('.error')`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I missed that.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Good call. Didn't fix it, but definitely made it nicer to look at

Comment: Do you still get the error if you remove `$(this).remove()`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `fadeOut` is being called on the `.error` siblings of `$(field)`, not on `$(field)` itself.

Is this what you are attempting to do? (ie: Remove $(field))?

```
field.siblings('.error').fadeOut(200, function() {
    field.remove();
});
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is validation. If there is an error, a div is appended to the erroneous fields parent div, making it a sibling of field. On successful validation, it will then fade the error div out and remove it. When the form is actually submitted, it looks for     $('.error').length == 0

Comment: I would suspect then, based on your error in the title, that the snippet of code you provided is NOT the issue. It might only be exposing the issue. Would you be able to create a small jsFiddle that emulates the error and post the link here?